# In what situation would 'a != a' resolve to true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

Looking through the code of svelte.js I found this odd looking function:

```js
function not_equal(a, b) {
    return a != a ? b == b : a !== b;
}
```

Can someone explain to me in what situation comparing a variable with it self for inequality would resolve to false?

I know that `!=` and `==` are weaker comparison operators than `!==` and `===` because they don't really care about the type but I still can't figure out what makes the `not_equal` function different from a simple `a !== b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways:

1. If `a` is `NaN`: `NaN` is not equal to anything, including itself.

```js
let a = NaN;
console.log(a != a); // true
```

I think this is the likely reason for that conditional operator in `not_equal`, since with that function `not_equal(NaN, NaN)` is `false` (e.g., it considers NaN equal to itself). It's not clear to me why they went with the `==` rather than `===` in `b == b`, though.

2. *(This doesn't apply to your function, just the `a != a` question.)* If `a` is a property with a getter function that returns a different value when called twice in succession (because it returns a random value, or a value that changes over time, or the getter mutates the value, etc.) being used within a `with` statement (very unlikely), or similar using a Proxy rather than a `with`.

```js
const obj = {
    get a() {
        return Math.random();
    }
};
with (obj) {
    console.log(a != a); // PROBABLY true
}
```

(**Note**: There are very good reasons not to use `with`, and it can't be used in strict mode.)

Other than that, I can't think of a way `a != a` would be `true`.